# problema con else en python 2

Tags: python

estoy teniendo problemas con la sintaxis de python2 al imprimir la sentencia else...
    me gustaria saber en que estoy fallando, no me llevo bien con python. =(

```
dia=raw_input("ingrese dia:").lower()
if (dia == "viernes"):
      dni=int(input("ingrese su dni:"))
    if (dni > 10000000):
    dni=str(dni % 10) 
    if (dni <= "1"): 
     cuil=int(input("ingrese su cuil"))
else 
    print("dni no coincide con el dia"
```

Comment: Te faltan los dos puntos después del `else`, debe ser `else:` y cerrar el paréntesis del último `print` (aunque no son necesarios en Python 2). ¿Podrías explicar el problema y el erro o errores que tienes exactamente? No uses `input` en python 2 para entradas de usuario, usa `raw_input`, es más no uses Python 2, está obsoleto y a alcanzado su EOL en Enero de este año.

Comment: Por otro lado `if (dni <= "1"):`  siempre va a ser falso, `dni` es un entero y `"1"` un literal de cadena (`str`).